# How to implement logic of Reading data from CSV file & store in JavaDB (in form of table) using servlets & jsp in my following code?

Tags: java, csv, derby

Contents of my csv file are like:

"outlook VARCHAR(128),temperature REAL,humidity VARCHAR(128) , & so, on.....

sunny,85,high .... & so, on...."

In my following code I want to read data from first line of file, splitting through comma, bracket and space and then create corresponding columns in table (javadb). 
First in my view page I created form to upload file then, in Controller servlet I handled parameter & pass it to DatabaseDAO class to read file & create table in database(corresponding to data that is stored in first line of file).
Its' not creating any table in database... Need help please

```
 (designview.jsp)
</form>
    <form name="fileForm" action="Controller" method="post" enctype=
     "multipart/form-data"
    <input type="file" name="page" size="20" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Upload" />
</form>

(Controller.java)
@MultipartConfig
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse
response)     
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String pageName=(String)request.getParameter("page");
    switch (pageName) {
     case "file":
            try{                   
                DatabaseDAO fOB=new DatabaseDAO();
                File myFile = new File("pageName");
                myFile.getAbsolutePath();
                fOB.FileRead(myFile);                  
            }catch (IOException e){
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
             ex);
    }
            break;
    }
}
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}

(DatabaseDAO.java)
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class DatabaseDAO {

String []tokens = null;

public static void main(String[] args){
try{
    System.out.println("file uploaded");
}catch(Exception e){}
}

public void FileRead(File st) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException,
IOException{

try{

    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("st"); BufferedReader br = new
BufferedReader(fr)) {

        String line=br.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            tokens = line.split("\\s+|\\(+|\\,+");
        }

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SmartMiner";

        try (Connection con = 
        DriverManager.getConnection(url,"PKG","diaaman")) {
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            for (int i = 0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
                String colname;
                colname = tokens[i];
                String colval;
                colval = tokens[i+1];
                int colrange;
                colrange=Integer.parseInt(tokens[i+2]);
                String sql="CREATE TABLE SmartMiner"+
                           "("+colname+colval+"("+colrange+"))";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }

            con.close();
        } 
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }

}
catch(IOException ioEx){
    System.out.println(ioEx);
}
}

}
```

Comment: Please give me some suggestions.................

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question. I recommend that you break your overall project into multiple smaller subprojects.

You'll also find, as you do so, that there are import design decisions that you have to make that will govern the implementation of your project:

1. How many tables do you want to use? Does all your CSV data go into a single table, or do you divide it among tables in some way?
2. What data types will you encounter in your CSV data? String data? Numeric data? Date/time data? How will you recognize which type of data you are processing?
3. What sort of data patterns represent errors in your data stream, and what will you do when you encounter those errors?

Use the principles of agile programming to take this large task and decompose it into smaller tasks that  you can work on incrementally, then build your way up to a complete working program:

1. Write and test code that can read lines of code from text files
2. Write and test code that can take a single line of text and break it down into a list of comma-separated values, obeying things like quotation marks, etc.
3. Write and test code that can create database tables, with columns of certain names and types
4. write and test code that can locate the table of the appropriate name, with the appropriate columns in it, and can formulate and execute an INSERT statement into that table.

By breaking things down into smaller tasks your overall project won't seem so enormous and you'll make progress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... First of all I give answers of your questions.

Comment: 1. There will be only one table and all the CSV data will go into a single table.                                                                                                                  2. There can be any type of data in CSV file. It can be string, numeric etc.     I have to recognize it in code that what will be the data type.                       3. For now I am not considering about those errors in my data stream.. After understanding my logic you can give me your suggestions about handling those errors.

Comment: I have edited my code to make my logic more clear to you.... Please see it & give your suggestion. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: It looks like you are making progress, good. Using String.split() to parse your line seems like a good first start. Your CREATE TABLE statement needs to have N columns, where N is the number of columns in your CSV. The easiest first prototype would be to make each column VARCHAR to avoid the datatypes complications. Note also that you only want to issue CREATE TABLE once; from then on, you use a PreparedStatement with an INSERT in it, and a bunch of setString calls to load your tokens into the INSERT, and you execute() the INSERT once per line from your CSV file. Good luck!

Comment: According to my above code, there is no creation of table in database & its' not showing any data. Please figure out my mistake

Comment: Simplify your problem: (1) run your program as a standalone program, not as a servlet. (2) don't try to store data in the database just yet; demonstrate to yourself that you can correctly parse the CSV file and display the parsed output.